# airflow cron schedule interval not triggering DAG properly

Tags: python, cron, airflow, airflow-scheduler

```
Airflow-version: **1.10.10** 

Cron: "30 07,08,11,15 * * *"
```

The DAG is expected to run at `7:30, 8:30, 11:30, 15:30`
but always DAG will start to trigger from `11:30, 15:30, 19:30, 20:30`
where `19:30, 20:30` is not mentioned in cron expression at all.

Appreciate if anyone help to debug this issue.

code:

```
CRON_SCHEDULER = "30 07,08,11,15 * * *" 
with DAG(
    "cron_test_dag",
    schedule_interval=CRON_SCHEDULER,
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2021, 1, 1, tz="UTC"),
    catchup=False) as dag:
    start_job = DummyOperator(task_id='Start_Job', dag=dag)
    bash_task1 = BashOperator(
        task_id="bash_task1",
        bash_command="echo hello world",
        dag=dag,
    )
    start_job >> bash_task1
```

Comment: Try this : "30 7,8,11,15 * * *"

Comment: I already checked this,  did not worked.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. Please share your code.

Comment: @EladKalif updated code pasted

Comment: I can not reproduce this on newer Airflow versions. My suggestion is to upgrade your Airflow version.

Answer (score 1):

As the offset is 3 hours exactly, I suggest trying to change your timezone. Are you in the UTC timezone as your code suggests? Maybe you should change it to UTC+03.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason it is interpreting 07,08 as pm hours: 19, 20.

I've just tested with the latest version of croniter (used by airflow) and it seems to work as expected, nevertheless the leading 0.

I've tested it with several versions back.

I don't see any bug filed with similar problem to croniter, so I suspect Airflow, but I don't see any bug filed there either…